# XSL: How do I escape the scope of document()?

Tags: variables, xslt, scope, document

I am currently trying to create an xsl document that uses a value from the current xml as well as an externally referenced document using select='document()'.

My code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <results>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//TestLog"/>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TestLog">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select='data/testcase/id'/>
    <testcase>
      <xsl:attribute name="internalid">
        <xsl:value-of select="document('internal_ids.xml', /)//testcase[custom_fields/custom_field/value=$id]/@internalid"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <desc><xsl:value-of select="data/testcase/description"/></desc>
      <more_data><xsl:value-of select="data/testcase/more_data"/></more_data>
    </testcase>
  </xsl:template>
```

The problem is that I want to get the internal id of the testcase in the internal_ids.xml that has the same pid as the TestLog. I can't use 'variable' because it doesn't change dynamically for each TestLog processed, but I need some way to reference the id of the current TestLog being processed, while inside the document()'s scope. Using 'xsl:variable' sets ALL testcase internalid's to the same value, since variable doesn't change. Instead of using variable, can I reference the TestLog node within the document() scope somehow, so that I can test value='data/testcase/id' without that XPATH referencing document()'s data/testcase/id?

internal_ids.xml:

```
<testsuite>
  <testcase internalid="123" name="stuff">
    <custom_fields>
      <custom_field>
        <name>pid</name>
        <value>TC-878</value>
      </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
  </testcase>
  <testcase internalid="456" name="stuff2">
    <custom_fields>
      <custom_field>
        <name>pid</name>
        <value>TC-200</value>
      </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

original.xml:

```
<root>
  <TestLog>
    <data>
      <testcase>
        <id>TC-878</id>
        <description>Foo bar foo bar</description>
        <more_data>More data is here</more_data>
      </testcase>
    </data>
  </TestLog>
  <TestLog>
    <data>
      <testcase>
        <id>TC-200</id>
        <description>Blah blah</description>
        <more_data> baz </more_data>
      </testcase>
    </data>
  </TestLog>
</root>
```

And my desired output.xml:

```
<results>
  <testcase internalid="123">
    <desc>Foo bar foo bar</desc>
    <more_data>More data is here</more_data>
  </testcase>
  <testcase internalid="456">
    <desc>Blah Blah</desc>
    <more_data> baz </more_data>
  </testcase>
</results>
```

Comment: Can you show us an input sample and the output you want to create? As for accessing the `TestLog` element, why can't you use the a variable to store that?

Comment: Updated with inputs and outputs!

Comment: Now with the samples as posted I fail to see why your posted XSLT with the variable inside the template for `TestLog` does not work. Can you explain in which way it fails to give you the result you want.

Comment: Instead of two different internalid's in the output, I get just one for both of them - <testcase internalid="123"> and <testcase internalid="123">

Comment: @Mindputty Please post a complete, reproducible example. Currently, your `internal_ids.xml` document has no root element and cannot be processed as XML. -- In addition, please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I'm using 1.0, but I'm not restricted to that and can change to 2.0 if that provides a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <results>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TestLog">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select='data/testcase/id'/>
    <testcase>
      <xsl:attribute name="internalid">
        <xsl:value-of select="document('internal_ids.xml')/testsuite/testcase[custom_fields/custom_field/value=$id]/@internalid"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <desc><xsl:value-of select="data/testcase/description"/></desc>
      <more_data><xsl:value-of select="data/testcase/more_data"/></more_data>
    </testcase>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to the following input documents:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <TestLog>
    <data>
      <testcase>
        <id>TC-878</id>
        <description>Foo bar foo bar</description>
        <more_data>More data is here</more_data>
      </testcase>
    </data>
  </TestLog>
  <TestLog>
    <data>
      <testcase>
        <id>TC-200</id>
        <description>Blah blah</description>
        <more_data> baz </more_data>
      </testcase>
    </data>
  </TestLog>
</root>
```

**internal_ids.xml**

```
<testsuite>
  <testcase internalid="123" name="stuff">
    <custom_fields>
      <custom_field>
        <name>a testcase</name>
        <value>TC-878</value>
      </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
  </testcase>
  <testcase internalid="456" name="stuff2">
    <custom_fields>
      <custom_field>
        <name>Another testcase</name>
        <value>TC-200</value>
      </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

returns:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <testcase internalid="123">
      <desc>Foo bar foo bar</desc>
      <more_data>More data is here</more_data>
   </testcase>
   <testcase internalid="456">
      <desc>Blah blah</desc>
      <more_data> baz </more_data>
   </testcase>
</results>
```

---

It would be preferable to use a **key** to get the value from the other document - esp. if using XSLT 2.0, where keys work across documents.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It doesn't work for me, but I didn't give the exact inputs that I'm working with on my machine, and it's affecting the output somehow. I'll need to go back and check everything... perhaps I will repost all of my code once I do... :(

Comment: The output that I get has <testcase internalid="">

Comment: @Mindputty We can only work with what you give us. The result above has been produced using the exact three documents pasted(!) into my post, and verified using three different XSLT 1.0 processors. -- Note that I had all three documents in the same directory.

Comment: This answer was useful in that it made me realize it was a type on my part deep in the code, since this answer code worked fine. Thank you again. I re-read my code and had test_case labelled as testcase...

Comment: Since this isn't a real issue, but rather just my mistake, should I delete this thread?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: "*I re-read my code and had test_case labelled as testcase..*" That would account for the value being empty - not for the value being the same for both nodes, as you reported initially.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was this, but I think it could be because it was in the wrong area - declared under <testcase> instead of at the start of the TestLog template before other tags.